# C# Combo Box - Selected items open different forms

Tags: c#, combobox

*Sorry if this sounds very stupid but I am new to C# and just trying to learn the basics.*
Anyway, I have a bunch of options listed in my combo box and want each option to open a different form.
How would I go about doing this?
I tried many variations that I have seen on YouTube and can't seem to find a good solution

Comment: Please show at least one of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectedIndexChange` action from `ComboBox`.

Like this:

```cs
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((ComboBox)sender).Text);
            // use your logic to open other forms, like somethings like this;
            string comboBoxItem = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
            if(comboBoxItem == "form1"){
                // open form1
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you know its winforms?

Comment: usually `combo box` is windows forms components, right? and he needed to open others forms